# How to import multiple mongo collections into algolia and get related parameter via API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server, algolia

I would like to integrate my app into algolia for implementing common search.

I already have Node JS (parse server) with MLAB mongo db for back-end. And my mongo db has multiple collection.

For easy understanding, lets define the sample collections below

Collection 1: **Order**

```
{
    "_id": "01LS0PnHCR",
    "title": "Test Title",
    "when": {
        "$date": "2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "_p_orderData": "OrderData$02OOnDuJnM", // Reference of OrderData collection -> 02OOnDuJnM
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-27T12:24:30.449Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-02-01T12:48:46.026Z"
    },
    "_p_user": "_User$hCiOOgQkOC"       // Reference of _User collection -> hCiOOgQkOC
}
```

Collection 2: **OrderData**

```
{
    "_id": "02OOnDuJnM",
    "orderDescription": "Test Description",
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-11T21:23:01.132Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-11T21:23:01.132Z"
    }
}
```

Collection 3: **OrderComment**

```
{
    "_id": "04tNm4U7sm",
    "_p_order": "Order$01LS0PnHCR",     // Reference of Order collection -> 01LS0PnHCR
    "type": "text",
    "comment": "cute",
    "_p_user": "_User$BKOIWDtzQ0",      // Reference of _User collection -> BKOIWDtzQ0
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-06T13:47:14.478Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-06T13:47:14.478Z"
    }
}
```

Collection 4: **_User**

```
{
    "_id": "hCiOOgQkOC",
    "username": "testing",
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-01-11T07:52:14.157Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-02-09T22:13:16.904Z"
    },
    "firstName": "Tes",
    "email": "testing@gmail.com",
    "lastName": "Ing"
}
```

My question has follows

1. How to import the above 4 collections to algolia?
2. I would like to search based on title, description, user (username, first name, lastname and email) - Searchable attributes
3. And if any matching records found then, it will be in the order of (Eg: My search word is 'Title')

`{
     "Object_ID": "XXXXXXXX",       // it is from algolia
     "_id": "01LS0PnHCR",           // Order ID
     "_p_orderData": "OrderData$02OOnDuJnM",
     "_p_user": "_User$hCiOOgQkOC",
     "username": "testing",
     "firstName": "Tes",
     "lastName": "Ing",
     "title": "Test Title",
     "orderDescription": "Test Description" 
}`

Note: The above response is for sample output, i know it come up with nbHits, nbPages, hitsPerPage etc.,

Any idea to implement the above scenario?

Thanks in advance!